# What is can.Control in canJS and why is it needed?

Tags: canjs, canjs-control

What is can.Control in canJS? any detailed examples would be helpful

To my understanding can.control is used for tabs and grids within the html.

Answer (score 1):

can.Control is the "Control" part of the MVC framework. You can use it to create modular widgets of any kind.

http://canjs.com/docs/can.Control.html